# Prove that a random graph $G(n,p)$ with $p \geq \ln(n)/(n-1)$ is connected with high probability

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Similar versions of this question has been posted before, but a complete solution was never posted from what I can see. I have an attempt at a solution which I'd like to have checked for errors.

I have a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, and the probability of any two vertices having an edge is $p \geq \frac{\ln n}{n-1}$.

Now, take some subset $G_i$ of the graph $G$ and let $g_i$ be the number of vertices in $G_i$. I want to prove that the likelihood of there being no edge connecting a vertex in $G_i$ to a vertex outside $G_i$ is very unlikely.

Firstly, consider the case $g_i = 1$.

We have that $$P[\:\nexists \text{ an edge (u,v) for u,v}\in G] = (1-p)$$
Therefore since $g_i = 1$,
$$P[\:\nexists \text{ an edge from } G_i \text{ to } G_i^c] = (1-p)^{(n-1)}$$

Now  let $p = (1+\epsilon)\frac{\ln n}{n-1}$ where $\epsilon > 0$. Then $n-1 = \frac{1}{p}(1+\epsilon)\ln n$ so

$$(1-p)^{(n-1)} = (1-p)^{\frac{1}{p}(1+\epsilon)\ln n}$$

And now using the fact that in general for positive $p$, $(1-p)^{1/p} \leq 1/e$ I have that

$$(1-p)^{\frac{1}{p}(1+\epsilon)\ln n} \leq \frac{1}{e^{(1+\epsilon)\ln n}} = \frac{1}{n^\epsilon}$$

Therefore for $g_i = 1$ (an isolated vertex), the probability vanishes as $p$ increases further past the threshold of $\frac{\ln n}{n-1}$

Further, if $g_i = n$ then of course the graph is connected, so let $2 \leq g_i \leq n-1$. Therefore since we're comparing every vertex in $G_1$ to every vertex outside it,

$$P[\:\nexists \text{ an edge from } G_i \text{ to } G_i^c] = (1-p)^{g_i(n-g_i)}$$

Now I want to find the maximum value of $g_i$ for which the above probability is maximised. That is, where $y = g_i(n-g_i)$ is minimised. The expression $y$ can be thought of as a parabola where the domain is $g_i \in [2,n-1]$. It is quick to check that the minimum point occurs at $g_i = n-1$, therefore I have that

$$P[\:\nexists \text{ an edge from } G_i \text{ to } G_i^c] \leq (1-p)^{(n-1)(n-(n-1))} = (1-p)^{(n-1)}$$

But $(1-p)^{(n-1)}$ is the probability in the case of $g_i = 1$, which has already been shown to vanish as $p$ exceeds $\frac{\ln n}{n-1}$. Therefore the probability of any subset of $G$ being disconnected also vanishes.

Comment: What question are you asking? Do you want someone to verify your proof?

Comment: I assume you mean to say that the random variables governing the existence of each possible edge are independent.

Comment: You have shown for any *specified* set of vertices $V_0$, the probability that $V_0$ is isolated from the rest of the graph tends to zero. You *want* to show that with probability tending to zero, there does not exists *any* set of vertices $V_0$ with this property. You are missing union bounds over all subsets of vertices. [For instance, the probability of getting any specific side of a $n$-sided die is $1/n$ which tends to zero; but I can't say with high probability I get none of the sides when I roll the die]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I understand you correctly, I just need to consider the union of probabilities $\cup P(V_k \text{ is disconnected})$ Where there are $\sum_{i=1}^n {n \choose i}$ such subsets $V_k$.